# Pandas: Subtract-add data to consecutive rows by priority (based on condition) till value is reached

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes

My original one

```
df1
Out[10]: 
  id   country   tech  priority  2020  2021  2022
0  a    Malawi  solar         3   100   100   100
1  b    Malawi  solar         2   100   100   100
2  c  Maldives  solar         1   100   100   100
3  d  Maldives   wind         2    50    50    50
4  e  Maldives   wind         1    50    50    50
5  f  Malaysia  solar         2    30    30    30
6  g  Malaysia  solar         2    30    30    30
7  h  Malaysia  solar         1    30    30    30
```

The one with increments and reductions

```
df2
Out[11]: 
    country   tech  2020  2021  2022
0    Malawi  solar    10    20    30
1  Maldives   wind   -10   -50   -30
2   Malysia  solar    10    10    10
```

I want to add/subtract values on the first based on values-conditions of the second

For increments

- Increments always apply to the biggest priority id for each country and technology
- If we have the same priority, then divide value to be added by two
- Increments from 2021 onwards apply to already incremented 2020 column (and not to the intial df1 2021)

For reductions

- Reductions apply to the smallest priority id for each country and technology
- If we have the same priority, then divide value to be added by two
- If the amount to be reduced is larger than what can be subtracted then roll to the next biggest priority level
- Subtractions from 2021 onward apply to already subtracted 2020 values (and not to initial df1 2021)

I want my output to look like this

```
df3
Out[12]: 
  id   country   tech  priority  2020  2021  2022
0  a    Malawi  solar         3   110   130   160
1  b    Malawi  solar         2   100   100   100
2  c  Maldives  solar         1   100   100   100
3  d  Maldives   wind         2    50    40    10
4  e  Maldives   wind         1    40     0     0
5  f  Malaysia  solar         2    35    40    45
6  g  Malaysia  solar         2    35    40    45
7  h  Malaysia  solar         1    30    30    30
```

Any help or direction is much appreciated

```
df1 = {'id':  ['a', 'b','c','d','e','f','g','h'],

        'country':['Malawi','Malawi','Maldives','Maldives','Maldives','Malaysia','Malaysia','Malaysia'],
        'tech':['solar','solar','solar','wind','wind','solar','solar','solar'],
        'priority':[3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1],
        '2020' : [100, 100, 100, 50, 50, 30, 30, 30],
        '2021' : [100, 100, 100, 50, 50, 30, 30, 30],
        '2022' : [100, 100, 100, 50, 50, 30, 30, 30]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame (df1, columns = ['id','country','tech','priority','2020','2021','2022'])

df2 = {'country' : ['Malawi','Maldives','Malaysia'],
        'tech':['solar','wind','solar'],
        '2020':[10,-10,10],
        '2021':[20,-50,10],
        '2022':[30,-30,10]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame (df2, columns = ['country','tech','2020','2021','2022'])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  This is a great, well-specified question.  You might benefit from breaking it up into separate questions, though, since the operation you're trying to do is a bit complicated.

Comment: This also feels like a course work assignment. Please make an earnest attempt and return with **specific** question.